# Hadoop Recursive Map

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a requirement that my mapper may in some cases produce a new key/value for another mapper to handle.  Is there a sane way to do this?  I've thought about writing my own custom input format (queue?) to achieve this.  Any Ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT:  I should clarify

**Method 1**

```
Map Step 1
(foo1, bar1) -> out1
(foo2, bar2) -> out2
(foo3, bar3) -> (fooA, barA), (fooB, barB)
(foo4, bar4) -> (fooC, barC)

Reduction Step 1:
(out1) -> ok
(out2) -> ok
((fooA, barA), (fooB, barB)) -> create Map Step 2
((fooC, barC)) -> also send this to Map Step 2

Map Step 2:
(fooA, barA) -> out3
(fooB, barB) -> (fooD, barD)
(fooC, barC) -> out4

Reduction Step 2:
(out3) -> ok
((fooD, barD)) -> create Map Step 3
(out4) -> ok

Map Step 3:
(fooD, barD) -> out5

Reduction Step 3:
(out5) -> ok

-- no more map steps. finished --
```

So it's fully recursive.  Some key/values emit output for reduction, some generate new key/values for mapping.  I don't really know how many Map or Reduction steps i may encounter on a given run.

**Method 2**

```
Map Step 1
(foo1, bar1) -> out1
(foo2, bar2) -> out2
(foo3, bar3) -> (fooA, barA), (fooB, barB)
(foo4, bar4) -> (fooC, barC)
(fooA, barA) -> out3
(fooB, barB) -> (fooD, barD)
(fooC, barC) -> out4
(fooD, barD) -> out5

Reduction Step 1:
(out1) -> ok
(out2) -> ok
(out3) -> ok
(out4) -> ok
(out5) -> ok
```

This Method would get the mapper to feed it's own input list.  I'm not sure which way would be simpler in the end to implement.

Comment: Did I understood right that different inputs has different depth of MR processing? Some a processing by one MR, while others need a chain?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.  A good analogy would be a recursive directory listing. The mapper would take a directory, and would emit files.  if I hit another directory, i would feed it back into the mapper.

Comment: Wait, i think it's more the other way around. I meant to say It would be analogous to a mapper that takes files, and emits them.  If one of the files happens to be a directory, it would read the contents of the directory, and feed each file back into the mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Method 1" way of doing recursion through Hadoop forces you to run the full dataset through both Map and reduce for each "recursion depth". This implies that you must be sure how deep this can go AND you'll suffer a massive performance impact.

Can you say for certain that the recursion depth is limited?

If so then I would definitely go for "Method 2" and actually build the mapper in such a way that does the required recursion within one mapper call.
It's simpler and saves you a lot of performance.

Comment: Yes I can say for sure that recursion depth is limited.  I'm leaning more towards a Method2 style myself.  When the mapper needs to emit more mapper input, it's -very- computationally expensive.  I think if i just kept recursively feeding the exact same mapper input, I wouldn't have very good load balancing.  But I do agree 100% that simpler = better

Comment: From experience with Hadoop I can say that a lot of the CPU time I really mean A LOT) goes into the reading and writing of records. Your "Method 1" does 3 Map-Reduce steps that must read and write all of the data over and over again (note: limiting to only the records that need to go to the latest steps is "hard). Without actually testing it I'm really sure the "Method 2" will take at least 3 times as long as "Method 1" and will be harder to implement. Just my 2ct.

Answer (score 1):

Use oozie [Grid workflow definition language] to string together two M/R jobs with first one only having mapper.
http://yahoo.github.com/oozie

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that i'm using Amazon Elastic MapReduce.  They don't support oozie yet :(  But it seems like a very interesting framework.  I didn't get far enough into the documentation to see if i could really get a recursive behavior out of it, but i'm going to absolutely keep it on the radar.

Answer (score 1):

In best of my understanding Hadoop MR framework in the beginning of the job is planning what map tasks should be executed and is not ready for the new map tasks to appear dynamically.

I would suggest two possible solutions:
a) if you emit another  pairs during map phase - feed them to the same mapper. So mapper will take its usual arguments and after processing will look into some kind of the internal local queue for additional  pairs to process. It will work good if there are small sets of the secondary  pairs, and data locality is not that important.

b) If indeed you are processing directories or something similar - you can iterate over the structure in the main of the job package, and built all splits you need right away.

Comment: Yeah, I must hate myself, since it always seems like i want to use MR in ways it wasn't designed!  Ok so i've thought about this kind of method. For most cases I expect I would need to emit very many pairs (100 or less).  Although in some cases I will have to emit well into the thousands of pairs. So if there is some kind of way I could get away with Hadoop choosing where to send my pairs (instead of my mapper feeding itself), I'd be better off.

Comment: I think it depends on the cost of processing per pair. May be thousands pair for the local mapper is not a problem. I suggest to measure the impact of the local mapper processing.

Comment: @DavidGruzman how can you do the a) part? -> 'feed them to the same mapper'. It seems to be a brilliant idea!